# How to use chruby with sudo and foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, sudo, chruby

I am trying to use sudo with chruby and foreman, but without success.

I tried

```
$ sudo chruby-exec ruby-2.1.2 -- foreman
$ foreman: command not found
```

But the same command with `rake` command works fine.

```
$ sudo chruby-exec ruby-2.1.2 -- rake --version
$ rake, version 10.1.0
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I haven't any ruby installed at root or at system, only at user.

Comment: What is error? Do you have any error output?

Comment: @ekremkaraca, only command not found, i am using chruby-0.3.8 with source.sh and auto.sh inside .bashrc of user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran `$ sudo chruby-exec ruby-2.1.2 -- gem install foreman` (as user) to install the gem inside chruby root user path and it is working now.

To install the ruby to root:

```
sudo ruby-install ruby 2.1.2
```

To install the gem inside chruby root path:

```
sudo chruby-exec ruby-2.1.2 -- gem install foreman
```

To use foreman like a root:

```
sudo chruby-exec ruby-2.1.2 -- foreman
```

From docs:

```
Correctly sets $GEM_HOME and $GEM_PATH.
Users: gems are installed into ~/.gem/$ruby/$version.
Root: gems are installed directly into /path/to/$ruby/$gemdir.
```